# Laravel call controller action from other controller

Tags: laravel, api, events, laravel-5, model-view-controller

I have a `post` model, a `user` model, and a `point` model.

Whenever a user posts a new post, they get a point added (new row in points table).

I have controllers setup for each of those models.

Should/how can I call the `PointsController@store` from the `PostsController@store` after adding the post?

Or is this the wrong way to go about it?

[Full code on GitHub](http://github.com/mwargan/JustBookr)

Comment: `$controller = new PointsController; $controller->store();`

Comment: I'd have to pass a bit more data in like the quantity of points... But is this even the right approach?

Comment: Do have a relationship setup between post and point model? If you do $post->point->create([]); You def don't want to call the controller for this. Or maybe $post->user->point->create([]); make sure you have the columns in fillable in the point model

Comment: No, the relationship is between the post and user, and the user and points. Aka User hasMany posts and hasMany points, but points and posts have no relationship

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz the store method should receive a Request as the first parameter so it is not a good idea to call it. You should always use models and relationships for that

Comment: @Michał then just do  $post->user->point->create([]); And you need to have the column you put in the create array in fillable. If you add mode info I can give you a better response. Like how the method where this happens looks and the relations in all 3 models.

Comment: Yeah you're right! Could I abstract this into a listener, since I have an event setup for each time a post is created? @Indra updated the question with full code ;)

Comment: @Michał yeah, that would probably be a good idea. It's called an observer. You can find that in the manual

Comment: @Indra if you'd be so kind to throw together an example as an answer that'd be awesome!!!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a modal.

For instance, in your `PointsController`:

```
public function store() {
    // your code
    User::addPoint(); // this is responsible for adding the point
}
```

And in your `PostsController`

```
public function store() {
    // your code
    User::addPoint(); // call this again
}
```

This way, you have a model responsible for updating the post.

Comment: Wait... what? :P

Comment: Michał he means to add a static function in User model. It's a sloppy way of doing it. The best way is with an observer. So your idea would work best. I'll try to post something in the next hours. @TaylorSwift you should never need to call a controller from another controller with very few exceptions and this is not one of them. Please read the question again. He even asked if this is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Option1: using models

In PostController

```
public function store(Request $request){
\Auth::user()->post()->create($request->all()); 
\Auth::user()->points()->create['point'=> 1]; // add your columns here
}
```

In Point model

```
protected $fillable = ['point']; //add here  list of columns you want to use on \Auth::user()->points->create['point'=> 1];
```

Option2: use an observer

create an observer class like here. I would make an Observers folder in app/

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#observers

Call it PostObserver

in PostObserver in create method:

```
 public function created(Post $post)
    {
        $post->user()->points()->create['point'=> 1]; // [column1=>value1, column2=>value2]
    }
```

In Point model

```
protected $fillable = ['point']; //add here  list of columns you want to use on \Auth::user()->points->create['point'=> 1];
```

In AppServiceProvider in method boot add

```
public function boot()
{
 Post::observe(PostObserver::class);
}
```

Don't forget to add the correct namespaces and then add use Observers\PostObserver in AppServiceProvider